# How to open modal after window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, reload, bootstrap-modal

I have code like this :

```
$("#savedata").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data: $("#savedata").serialize(),
    url : "<?php echo site_url('ppdb/simpan_data/'.$jenjang);?>",
    success : function(data){
        window.location.reload();
        $('#cekulang').modal('show');
    }
});
return false;
});
```

I want to open the modal after page done refreshing. but i got the modal open first then the page refreshing with that code.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Ideally nothing should run after `window.location.reload()`. Also if you want to show a modal after page is refreshed, you will have to write it on `Page Load` function. You can either set a parameter in url or use HTML5 storage to save a flag and process accordingly

Comment: Can't help thinking that `window.location.reload()` is not the best way to approach things. What is the benefit of doing that?

Comment: i want to fetch data from database that inserted by form in that page

Comment: You want to insert the data which is returned by your Ajax request into the page, then show your modal. Did I get that right?

Comment: @JackZelig no, i already insert the data then i want to call the data in that page too with a modal. the problem is the page reloaded after the modal show. i want the page reload first to get the variable from controller and then the modal show. sorry my english is bad

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "get the variable from the controller". Normally you'll get a response from the server which you process in some way (maybe by updating the DOM) and there is no need to refresh anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like:

```
success: function(data){
    window.location = window.location.href + "?openmodal=1";
}
```

And add in your body

```
<?php
    if($_GET['openmodal'] == 1){ ?>
        <script>
                 $(function(){
                     $('#cekulang').modal('show');
                 });
        </script>
<?php         
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, i have edited my answer, sorry for the late reply, wrap `$('#cekulang').modal('show');` inside a `$(function(){});`, you have probably placed the php script before the html markup of the modal has been loaded. This time the function will now wait for the page to load before executing `modal('show');`

Comment: sorry, change the if statement to `if(isset($_GET['openmodal']) && $_GET['openmodal'] == 1)`

Comment: no, its work. i'm wrong put the php code. thanks a lot